# exclude specific warnings in java project

Tags: java, gradle, protocol-buffers

How do i exclude warnings in specific classes or specific warnings.?

```
 tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.warnings = false
}
```

I tried the above script in my build.gradle which is excluding every warnings. 
I have been using google protobuf which is generating certain java classes which is not recommended to edit. these classes are created inside a specific directory. is it possible to exclude the warnings in the classes inside a specific directory?

Answer (score 0):

For gradle you can install the Gradle quality plugin from [github](https://github.com/xvik/gradle-quality-plugin) and use it to avoid the warnings:

to exclude files for check, for example:

```
quality {
   exclude '**/sample/**'
}
```